# How to clear transaction log in sybase15.7?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-asa, sybase-ase15

I'm using Sybase15.7, after many transactions I'm getting an error like
**The transaction log in database fims is almost full.  Your transaction is being
suspended until space is made available in the log.**
Help me resolving this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Read carefully doc about "dump transaction" http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/X47924.htm

The strategy is very different if you are running this in TEST/DEV or in PRODUCTION/PROD. I recommend you do lots of testing before doing anything in PROD.

If you are doing tests in a DEV/TEST environnment (no need of restoring the database), you could kill the process of the running transaction then you  truncate the logs by

- either setting the db option "trunc log on checkpoint" on the database "fims" and/or
- run "dump tran fims with truncate_only". If it does not work run ""dump tran fims with no_log".

If you are in a PRODUCTION environnement where logs are important to keep to restore the database later, you should truncate the logs into a file by running for example: "dump tran fims to /dev/fims01.log"